How to sort elements whose distance is constant?
I need to sort elements that has the same distance to each other (eg: the indicies create an arithmetic sequence)
For example, I have this std::vector
11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0

I only want to sort the elements with the indicies 1, 4, 7, 10,
(the corresponding values is 10, 7, 4, 1). The resulting array would look like this:
11, 1, 9, 8, 4, 6, 5, 7, 3, 2, 10, 0 

I have written this code:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

void sort_constant_jump(std::vector<int> &foo, int start, int jump)
{
    std::vector<int> need_to_sort;
    for(int index = start; index < foo.size(); index += jump)
    {
        need_to_sort.push_back(foo[index]);
    }

    std::sort(need_to_sort.begin(), need_to_sort.end());

    for(int index = 0; index < need_to_sort.size(); ++index)
    {
        foo[index * jump + start] = need_to_sort[index];
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> foo {11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0};

    sort_constant_jump(foo, 1, 3);

    for(int number : foo)
        std::cout << number << ' ';
}

But it needs to copy the elements first, which is unwanted. Is there anyway to do this in-place and not creating a seperate container, sorting it and assigning the solution again?

Are you trying for a subsequence sort?
Rather than calling std::sort() and reassigning the sorted indices, you just need to deal with the fixed indices of interest. For simplicity, even swapping smaller and larger elements as in Bubble sort can do it in place.

This question is similar to: Sort a sublist of elements in a list leaving the rest in place. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@HarshitGupta That duplicate doesn't seem anywhere close to this question and it's also in python.

@HarshitGupta Bubble sort is more inefficient than the STL

You're asking a yes/no question, after demonstrating that the answer is "yes", if you look at your question carefully.

One more thing: The values 1, 4, 7, 10 have the indices 10, 7, 4, 1. Can you clarify that you really mean indices, not values. Also, by what algorithm do you pick those? This really looks like two separate things and they are not sufficiently described yet.

For C++23 you can use stride_view, online demo : https://onlinegdb.com/WsqPcwj36
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> values{11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0};

    // drop(1) to skip 1st element
    // then only sort every 3rd element
    std::ranges::sort( values | std::views::drop(1) | std::views::stride(3) );
    
    std::cout << "Expected : 11 1 9 8 4 6 5 7 3 2 10 0\n";
    std::cout << "Actual   : ";
    
    for(const auto value : values)
    {
        std::cout << value << " ";
    }
}

The output will be:
Expected : 11 1 9 8 4 6 5 7 3 2 10 0
Actual   : 11 1 9 8 4 6 5 7 3 2 10 0 

...Program finished with exit code 0
Press ENTER to exit console.

